# What is the process for re-closing a re-opened question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, process

I and a sufficient number of others voted to close the [cars and phones](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/at-what-point-in-the-20th-century-did-automobiles-and-telephones-become-ubiquitou) question. Then a sufficient number of people voted to re-open it. Now we're discussing it here in Meta. Cool.

Beyond that: **What is the procedure for further determining the status of the question?**

I know that I cannot vote again to close it. My first vote counts and that's it. Do other people who haven't voted on the issue continue to vote to close it?

ETA: Also, what's the etiquette? Should people avoid voting to open or close it until we hash things out here in Meta or do we encourage people to keep voting?

Answer (score 4):

Other people can vote to close if they feel it's merited.  Eventually everyone who cares will have voted to close or reopen and the issue will be decided.

It is worth putting a comment on it driving people to a relevant meta discussion (in this case, we've made three, which isn't going to do anyone any favors). But there's no embargo rule that you must wait for that.  In the end, "do you click on the little button" is up to the individual user - if there was a rule to not do something while there was a discussion on meta, then there would be functionality for that.

Relevant links:

[Give Diamond Moderators the Ability to Partially Lock a Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/give-diamond-moderators-the-ability-to-partially-lock-a-post/34819#34819)

[Reopened questions shouldn't be able to be closed again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53188/reopened-questions-shouldnt-be-able-to-be-closed-again)